# Is it possible to cache base64 encoded images in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, caching, base64

I'm making a distributed social networking platform and thus need to display many possibly duplicate images e.g. for profile pictures. The network topology requires each web client to connect to multiple servers via websockets, thus the images are not coming from the same server that is serving the web app itself. I'm currently transmitting images to the client encoded using base64 and displaying them using `<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">`, but I'm concerned that this data is potentially duplicated across hundreds of individual images.

The solutions I've considered are:

- Serve images via HTTP instead of over websockets using base64: I don't want to require each chat server to also be a web server to reduce complexity and reduce the number of ports that must be forwarded.
- Cache the images on the web server that serves the web app: I would rather the web app is able to be served from a standard apache or nginx server, which is not able to understand my custom protocol.

I'm wondering, is there any way to get around this? Perhaps some way of specifying an image with the base64 and referencing it elsewhere?

To be clear, the images are only transmitted once from the server, but to *display* them multiple times seems to require duplication client-side.

EDIT: Real world performance, with 300 128x128 pixel images (which is realistic of what I'd expect) running on my local machine.

| Metric | Base64 | Served via HTTP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Memory | 95.01MB | 3.90MB |
| Page load time | 700-900ms | 130-170ms |

From this I would conclude that it could be a performance problem, and although it's not unusable *right now*, it's a lot more memory than I'd like to be using and the page does feel fairly slow to load.

Comment: First of all, is this a case of [Premature Optimization](https://xkcd.com/1691/)? Have you measured client performance and found a problem? If so, is the problem time or memory? In which clients does it appear? Will it actually affect your users?   If this is a real problem, you can solve it by sending the image as a separate non-displayed element and using an event to pull the image into the place(s) you want it displayed. This might not save any memory or time, though; depends on the browser and the details.

Comment: @RogerDurham very good point actually, i have not measured it (probably because I do not have a really functioning app yet), I will put together a test and measure some real world performance numbers

Comment: "Perhaps some way of specifying an image with the base64 and referencing it elsewhere?" — The whole point of using Base64 is so you can express the image as text so it will fit in a data URL so you can **avoid** referencing it elsewhere. If you want to reference it elsewhere then use HTTP(S) URLs. These don't, necessarily, have to be served by either the HTTP server that serves the web app or the servers that host the web socket services.

Comment: @Quentin where else would they be served from? The web socket servers are the authority on the image content, and I would like to avoid relying on external services as much as possible.

Comment: Wherever you like / can get the images to.

Comment: @Quentin that's my problem, I don't think there is anywhere sensible I can get my images to. I don't want to have some centralised server that deals with images because the point of this project is to be distributed.